# Maps API changed tile size resulting in wrong coordinates

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Dear all please help me on the following. I found below piece of code and addapted it a little for my own use. Now I enter the following problem. As you can see I use tiles with size 100 x 100 px instead of the normal 256 x 256 px tiles.

The map itself looks good, but the coordinates are a little messed up. For example you can see that I have to center the map to lat: 73 to get the "equator" in the center. Also you can see that the triangle that I construct is not repeated on the same place on the map if one scrolls in the y direction. You have to scroll 2.56 times around the world to find the next triangle instead of finding it after exact 1 time.

Now the question is, can I fix the coordinate setting in some way? Or can I somehow use the normalized x and y coordinates to place my triangle?

The map can be viewed at [magtest.r4u.nl](http://magtest.r4u.nl)

(I know the code needs to be cleaned up a little. Annotations such as "moon" are direct copies of the original code as I found it on the web)

```js
    function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 73, lng: 0},
    zoom: 3,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: ['moon']
    }
  });

 // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var triangleCoords = [
    {lat: 85, lng: 0},
    {lat: 85, lng: 30},
    {lat: 37, lng: 10}
  ];

  var triangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  triangle.setMap(map);

  var moonMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
        var normalizedCoord = getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom);
        if (!normalizedCoord) {
          return null;
        }
        var bound = Math.pow(2, zoom);
        return '//magtest.r4u.nl/map/' + zoom + '/' + normalizedCoord.x + '/' + (bound - normalizedCoord.y - 1) + '.png';
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(100, 100),
    maxZoom: 14,
    minZoom: 3,
    radius: 10000,
    name: 'Moon'
  });

  map.mapTypes.set('moon', moonMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('moon');
}

// Normalizes the coords that tiles repeat across the x axis (horizontally)
// like the standard Google map tiles.
function getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom) {
  var y = coord.y;
  var x = coord.x;

  // tile range in one direction range is dependent on zoom level
  // 0 = 1 tile, 1 = 2 tiles, 2 = 4 tiles, 3 = 8 tiles, etc
  var tileRange = 1 << zoom;

  // don't repeat across y-axis (vertically)
  if (y < 0 || y >= tileRange) {
    return null;
  }

  // repeat across x-axis
  if (x < 0 || x >= tileRange) {
    x = (x % tileRange + tileRange) % tileRange;
  }

  return {x: x, y: y};
}
```

Comment: I tried to place the tilesize statement elsewhere in the code, but that didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot I found the following solution. I added below code to adjust the coordinates to the right tile size.

```js
moonMapType.projection = {
    fromLatLngToPoint: function(latLng) {
      var latRadians = latLng.lat() * Math.PI / 180;
      return new google.maps.Point(
         100 * (0.5 + latLng.lng() / 360),
          100 * (0.5 - 0.5 * Math.sin(latRadians)));
    },
    fromPointToLatLng: function(point) {
      var x = point.x / 100;
      var y = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, point.y / 100));

      return new google.maps.LatLng(
          Math.asin(1 - 2 * y) * 180 / Math.PI,
          -180 + 360 * x);
    }
```

The polygon is now showing only on the first -180 to +180 degrees of the map. When I scroll to the right or left, as soon as I scroll more than 180 degrees, the map refreshes, deleting the polygon from the original map and replacing it on the map which is now in the center of my view port. It works fine for me, but if anyone knows how I could solve it that would be nice.